# Replace url with a different one before load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In google chrome extensions, How can i replace a request URL with a different one **before it loads**?

I took a look at [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) and i think one of them is what i am looking for, I don't know which one exactly.
 I believe google limits some kind of stuff, not sure if this is one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an example that does this :

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    // Redirect the original request to a given URL.
    var url = "http://site.com/image.png";
    return {redirectUrl: url};
  },
  // filters
  {
    urls: [
      "http://original.com/*"
    ],
    types: ["image"]
  },
  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking"]);
```